# Save each value from a serialized column and store them formated

Tags: php, mysql

For example, I have a column "interests" with a row that contains

```
$serializedResponse = a:2:{i:0;s:11:"Apple";i:1;s:7:"Pear";}
```

And I want to save the values in a php variable like:

```
$formatedVariable = "(Apple%|Pear%)"
```

Why?
Because I want to get some names from a json variable and then use those words as a search condition with PHP/MySQL (SIMILAR TO '(AA%|BBB%|CCC%')

I know I'll have to do:

```
$unserializedReponse = unserialize($serializedResponse)
```

And then, for each value in the array store them in a new variable with the formated options so I can use the search query properly. (In a way I can't figure out). Thank you very much :)!

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: use variables inside an array for using them as a search condition

Comment: In a query? Like using `IN`?

Comment: yes, that could work

Comment: `$formatedVariable = '('.implode('%|', $unserializedReponse).'%)';` But you probably want to quote the values as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $_REQUEST is equal to $_REQUEST = '["a value", "another value"]';

This will format the query to AND interests LIKE '%a value%' OR interests LIKE '%another value%';

```
<?php
// init
include_once 'db.php'; // connects to db

// gets each keyword
$resultVariable = json_decode($_REQUEST[interests]); // get values to search (orginial: json file)

// sets query
$formatedVariable = "SELECT id,name FROM users WHERE city = '$_REQUEST[city]' AND interests LIKE '%".implode("%' OR interests LIKE '%", $resultVariable)."%'"; // create a search condition for every keyword

$sql = $conn->prepare($formatedVariable); // search from the query
$sql->execute(); // execute query
$array = $sql->fetchAll(); // response

print_r(json_encode($array));

$conn = null;
?>
```

This will get the values from the selected columns in a json response.